# "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" error when using multiple files

Tags: c++

I get this error when importing a header and can't find why (C++ newbie here).

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "add.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "The addition result is " << myAddition(2,3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**add.cpp:**

```
#include "add.h"

int myAddition(int nb1, int nb2)
{
    return nb1+nb2;
}
```

**add.h:**

```
int myAddition(int nb1, int nb2);
```

When I try to compile main.cpp (using Atom and the "gpp-compiler" add-on in OS X 10.12.6), I get this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "myAddition(int, int)", referenced from:
>   _main in main-a2ca70.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It also says:

> Uncaught Callback must be a function

The Stack Trace is:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
>       at maybeCallback (fs.js:157:9)
>       at Object.fs.writeFile (fs.js:1290:14)
>       at ChildProcess.child.on (/Users/sessiondel/.atom/packages/gpp-compiler/index.js:299:12)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
>       at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:380:11)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:596:12)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you compiling ?

Comment: The gpp-compiler notice says "To compile C or C++, press F5 or right click the file in tree view and click Compile and Run" so I just press f5 in main.cpp! (It works well with a single file, but I don't manage to use multiple files).

Comment: please, open the terminal, go to the folder where the files are and try `g++ main.cpp add.cpp && ./a.out`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works in the terminal! The output is "The addition result is 5". Is it a problem with the way I use Atom?

Comment: i'll create a answer in order to help future possible people with the same problem, and in which i'll explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in C++ if you want to compile some code that is located in more than one file, you have to tell explicitly to the compiler where to find certain function, in this case the function `add`, so in order to achive this, you have to specify the files in to the compiler in this way:

```
g++ main.cpp add.cpp
```

and after the compiling, the compiler will generate a `a.out` file with the compiled file, and to run it just do `./a.out`.

Probably, Atom, not being a IDE for c++, just tries to compile that file, and the C++ compile can't find the function add in a `object file` (.o extension).

Comment: Thank you! After further research I finally use this: g++ main.cpp add.cpp -o main &&./main . It compiles and run it, and then I can also click on the executable if I want. I don't understand the problem with Atom but it works well with the terminal too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    g++ -c add.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
    g++ add.o main.o -o exe_name
```